# What's the correct form of MySQL query with scattered variables?

Tags: python, mysql

I already checked the questions related to this but I can't seem to find anything that is helping me in my problem.

```
    # this is the code that comes before the mysql query 
    select = request.args['select']
    print select # ["c9", "TEMP"]
    c, conn = connection()
    print "connected"
```

After I implement this query, it doesn't produce any data

```
data = c.execute("SELECT Client, %s, Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'", (select[1],select[0]))
# prints data = 0
```

this one produces an error with my sql query

```
data = c.execute("SELECT Client, '%s', Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = '%s' and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15';", (select[1],select[0]))
# (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\\"\'\', Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = (\'[\') and Date_Time > \'2016-04-26 18:17\' at line 1')
```

no data is produced from here as well

```
data = c.execute("SELECT Client, '%s', Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15';", (select[1],select[0]))
# prints data = 0
```

However, just putting this command and it works (no variables)

```
data = c.execute("SELECT Client, TEMP, Date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = 'c9' and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15';")
```

So where's my error? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use parameter substitution in the column list; you'd need to use normal Python string formatting there.

```
c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'".format(select[1]), select[0])
```

Comment: Thank you boss for your instant reply, but I got this error `(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'", date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = \'[\' and Date_Time > \'2016-04-26 18:17:15\'\' at line 1')` IDK why!l

Comment: Please ignore my last comment, boss. The line `select = request.args['select']` returns the value as a string, so I have to fix this by using `ast` library. However, after fixing that, I am now getting this `not all arguments converted during string formatting` Still working on it :)!

Comment: `c.execute("SELECT Client, {}, date_Time FROM data WHERE Client = %s and Date_Time > '2016-04-26 18:17:15'".format(select[1]), [select[0]])` We need to add the brackets at the end to make it work, boss. Please edit the answer so others when won't go through this too. :)